# CakePHP Username Encryption/Decryption

Tags: php, cakephp, encryption

In my CakePHP Application, I'm trying to encrypt the stored users' data, which I have done successfully for the most part. I can get the general encrypt/decrypt working with `beforeSave()` and `afterFind()`, but I run into issues when encrypting/decrypting usernames - the issue being that the AuthComponent looks into the database for an exact match to the entered username. I encrypt the username before sending it to the AuthComponent, but this won't do anything as it occurred to me encrypting a string (with `Security::rijndael` won't always produce the same result (as a hash will).

I've been poking around in the AuthComponent in the lib folder, but I'm hesitant to make any changes. So I guess I'm left with 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to have encrypted usernames in the database and have Cake read them? (I'm almost certain this is a yes so...)
2. How should I go about this? A Behavior maybe? A simple modification to AuthComponent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said, I don't see a reason to play with AuthComponent, I would just use [the Security Utility](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-Security.html#Security).

Like you already said, if you want to save a hash instead of plain text in database, then you will need to make use of the beforeSave() callback, your hash will be done using [Security::hash()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-Security.html#86).

It is important to notice that a HASH, by definition, cannot be decrypted. Thus, if what you really want is to encrypt/decrypt then you will need to use [Security::cipher()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-Security.html#137)

Comment: Thanks, but I already have encryption and decryption set up. I want the usernames to be recoverable so I have gone with encryption instead of hashing. When I add a new user, everything is encrypted fine. I can't login though because Cake is looking for *some encrypted string* in the Username column and that's different than the original encryption.

Comment: Then modify the username BEFORE logging the user. How? using cipher().

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my original post, I have updated it. I'm using `Security::rijndael` which does not produce the same result given the same string.